# SSL Certificate Match Error while calling Google Places API

Tags: google-places-api

I have been using Google Places API inside my application. The client code is written in Java. It was working fine till couple of weeks ago and suddenly it started throwing following exceptions while making API call:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: hostname in certificate didn't match: <maps.googleapis.com/209.85.175.95> != <*.googleapis.com> OR <googleapis.com> OR <*.googleapis.com>
```

I am using following URL for making API call : https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?

Also tried with different Google API keys generated from Google API console.

Can someone please point what I am missing here?

Many thanks

Comment: Please provide a sample of the code you are using to perform the API request.

Answer (score 1):

I used the latest Google API (version 1.13.2) which support better SSL options:

```
ApacheHttpTransport.Builder transport = new ApacheHttpTransport.Builder().doNotValidateCertificate().build();
```